# Assessing prediction accuracy for outcomes with varied event dates

Tags: forecasting

We are interested in coming up with a way to measure accuracy of prediction in forecasting durations to an expected event. On date X, individuals are asked to estimate when a certain event will occur (date Y). We then have the actual date that the event occurred (date Z). One simple way to calculate accuracy of prediction with this information would be using

Actual time to event (measured in days): Date Z $-$ Date X

Forecasted time to event (measured in days): Date Y $-$ Date X

Prediction accuracy $=$ 
[(Actual time to event) $-$ (Forecasted time to event)]/(Actual time to event)

While this equation would take into account overestimates (by having a positive value) and underestimates (by having a negative value), we fear that the prediction accuracy would be biased as not everyone has the same actual time to event. For some individuals, the actual time to event might be 14 days, whereas for others it may be 250 days. With this in mind, it is likely that there would be more chance for variability when the actual time to event was further in the future than when it is closer to the initial date X. We are interested in some type of prediction accuracy calculation which might adjust for this issue of some people having a longer actual time to event than others. We are new to the world of forecasting models and are wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to best deal with this problem.